# Fine to keep macbook on power for unlimited time?

Tags: battery

I just got a used Macbook Pro (retina) 2012 running El Capitan. I am keeping it charged and on all the time. Is there any harmful effect from doing so on the battery in the long term?

Comment: Have you read [Batteries - Maximizing Performance - Apple](http://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/)?

Comment: Yes. There do not seem to be any specific instructions for keeping it plugged in.

Comment: @Bob Rogers That's your answer, right there.

Answer (score 0):

Technically no, there is no damage done to it. But it is still smart to let it unplug and fully drain the power to keep it in tip-top shape.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in leaving your battery plugged in - your MacBook Pro will directly use the power adapter for its power needs. However, Apple (used to) recommend unplugging the battery occasionally - [**"An ideal use would be a commuter who uses her notebook on the train, then plugs it in at the office to charge. This keeps the battery juices flowing."**](http://web.archive.org/web/20140805204739/http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html)

There are other ways to improve your battery life, such as keeping it out of extreme cold and heat, and always updating to the latest Mac OS.

[(Source, in case you want to verify this)](http://web.archive.org/web/20140805204739/http://www.apple.com/batteries/notebooks.html)